# Add comInterfaceExternalProxyStub element to manifest during build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, com

I have c# class library where I'm using some unmanaged COM components. In the references for the COM components I set the Isolate=True which causes VS to output a Native.MyLibrary.manifest file during build.

In a Reg free scenario, the unmanaged COM code fails to run properly unless I add a `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub  />` element to the generated manifest.

Is there away to include the element automatically during a build, other than using some post build script ?

**More details**

The unmanaged COM component exposes a number of events which I wire up to. In a reg Free application, these events only fire when the original thread that wires the handler is MTA and the `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub  />` is present in the manifest of the library. I have tried STA threads with and without the interface stub but only calls *to* the COM functions work, events never fire under STA.

I have tried adding an app.manifest file to my project, and copying the entire contents of the previously generated Native.MyLibrary.manifest in (with InterfaceStub element). Then I turn off Isolated=True and rebuild. But VS unexpectedly adds a second `<comInterfaceExternalProxyStub  />` to the file semi complete with IID and TLBID Guids from the one I manually defined in the app.manifest in the project. The duplication of information in the manifest causes the calling application to throw an error.

My current workaround is to have the complete working manifest in a XML file in my project and then overwrite the VS generated Native.MyLibrary.manifest with it in a post build task.

Comment: That should not be necessary for a well-authored type library.  VS can figure it out from the type library content and the registry keys (HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\Interfaces).  You are not giving us anything to look at so it is just blind guessing, consider using a telephone.  Or add a manifest to your main EXE project and copy/paste the content of the .manifest file to it, Isolated back to False, so you only have to do it once.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I've updated the question with some more detail. I originally kept the question short as I've had trouble getting value out of long questions that "paint the picture" in the past. Let me know of any other info that would be useful and I'll happily add it. I don't want to add the manifest information to the main exe, I want the class library to be able to be consumed just like any other .NET library. Adding the ProxyStub element to the library manifest achieves just this.